# Is there any image viewer that supports animated SVG?

Tags: software-recommendation, animations, image-viewers, svg

I know we can view animated SVG files using web browsers. I wonder if there is a software that works exclusively as an image viewer with SVG animations support.

Answer (score 0):

Sketsa [SVG Editor](https://www.kiyut.com/products/sketsa/) supports animated SVG.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've never heard of that software. I tried to download it and I am getting an error when I try to extract the zip file. It looks very suspicious to me.

Comment: I didn't get an error when I tried to extract the zip file.